How to remove this link "Premium osclass themes and plugins" in front office of OSclass
How to remove the link that appears in the footer of OSclass "Premium osclass themes and plugins" If there is a css or a code the can help me remove this or customize it please help since i do not see the option to remove it. The screenshot of the link
I tried using "Inspect" to edit css to hide it but was not succesful. also tried to look for its location in the file manager but could not locate it. please give me steps or codes to remove it

What's the link to your website?

https://adverts.buzz/

This will do it:
a[href="https://osclasspoint.com/"]{
 display: none;
}

